# Set padding to element(div)

Tags: html, css

I'm trying set padding to my element like:

```
padding: 12 6 6 0px;
```

But google chrome labels it as invalid property value.

Setting padding works like this:

```
padding: 0 0 0 6px;
```

Where my mistake or ignorance?

Comment: for values <> 0 you have to specify a unit like the following: `em, px, vh, vw, %`.

Comment: which element you are appying for ??

Comment: Pretty much what everyone else said. It looks like you're adding the unit to the end of the property, when you should be adding it to each individual measurement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use measurement unit (in your case `px`) for every value.
So, your padding property should have a value of: `padding: 12px 6px 6px 0;`

Answer (score 1):

With the zero values, You don't have to add the 'px' or 'em', just leave it alone.

```
padding: 12px 6px 6px 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing unit (`px`) at the end of the value.

Do:

```
padding: 12px 6px 6px 0;
```

Instead of

```
padding: 12 6 6 0px;
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

In this line, 12 , 6 , 6 don't have units specified (either px,em or %). So, it does not work.

```
 padding: 12 6 6 0px;
```

But in this line, the number 6 has a unit in px. So it works.

```
padding: 0 0 0 6px;
```

What you're missing is that, 0 has no units. 0px,0% and 0em are all the same. And, any number <0 or >0 should be given a unit.